# Tracking a new data in Google Analytics Ecommerce

Tags: php, google-analytics, analytics

I use Google analytics tracking code to track my orders as in

```
<pre>

    <script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript">
    {literal}
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '-------']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
</pre>
```

I want to pass additional variable (Service information) to analytics and view it under Ecommerce > Overview  > As list under Top Revenue Sources.
I tried to edit the script by defining custom variable, but this appears in the Audience > Custom > Custom Variables section

Let me know how to add the new details under ecommerce overview.

Thanks!
Farhath

Answer (score 0):

You can't (not programmatically in any case). You'd have to store your value as a custom variable and then create a custom report that includes the value, or set the custom variable as secondary dimension in a standard report and create a shortcut.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I created a new custom variable - Product billing cycle with scope 3, and the data is shown in the page - Audience > Custom > Custom Variable. The only data shown : Transaction and Revenue under Conversion Sections. Is there any way to show which conversion it is in?

Comment: There is a goal set up - New Order, but in the custom variable, I cant see that conversion rate. Only Transaction and revenue are displayed. Any way to show the conversion too?